# Terminate called recursively while using multiple classes

Tags: c++

While trying to do some work with multiple classes, I'm having this error and it doesn't show anything else. Here is my malfunctioning class. The error occurs when i call the constructor on my main class. Can somebody identify the error please?

```
#ifndef ROBO_H
#define ROBO_H
    
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <queue>
    
using namespace std;
    
class Robo{
    public:
        Robo();
        Robo(int n);
        ~Robo();
        int get_aliens();
        int get_recursos();
        char** exec_comando(string s, char** map);
        char** executar(char** map);
        char** add_comando(string s, char** map);
        void print_registro();
    
    private:
        int robo_n;
        queue<string> comandos;
        queue<string> registro;
        int x,y;
        int aliens,recursos;
        int ativado;
        int aliens_base,recursos_base;
};
    
#endif
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
    
#include <queue>
#include "Robo.hpp"
    
Robo::Robo(){
    this->robo_n = 0;
    this->aliens = 0;
    this->recursos = 0;
    this->aliens_base = 0;
    this->recursos_base = 0;
    this->ativado = 0;
}
    
Robo::Robo(int n){
    this->robo_n = n;
    this->aliens = 0;
    this->recursos = 0;
    this->aliens_base = 0;
    this->recursos_base = 0;
    this->ativado = 0;
}
```

Since you guys requested, here is the rest of the class and my main:

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

#include <queue>
#include "Robo.hpp"

Robo::Robo(){
    this->robo_n = 0;
    this->aliens = 0;
    this->recursos = 0;
    this->aliens_base = 0;
    this->recursos_base = 0;
    this->ativado = 0;
}


Robo::Robo(int n){
    this->robo_n = n;
    this->aliens = 0;
    this->recursos = 0;
    this->aliens_base = 0;
    this->recursos_base = 0;
    this->ativado = 0;
}


Robo::~Robo(){
}


int Robo::get_aliens(){
    return this->aliens_base;
}


int Robo::get_recursos(){
    return this->recursos_base;
}


char** Robo::exec_comando(string s, char** map){
    string acao;
    stringstream ss(s);
    getline(ss,acao, ' ');
    if(acao == "MOVER" || acao == "*MOVER"){
        string acao_ind;
        getline(ss,acao_ind,' ');
        getline(ss,acao_ind,' ');
        int x_l = acao_ind[1];
        int y_l = acao_ind[3];
        if(map[x_l][y_l] == 'O'){
            string r = "IMPOSSIVEL MOVER PARA (";
            r = r.append(to_string(x_l));
            r = r.append(",");
            r = r.append(to_string(y_l));
            r = r.append(")");
            this->registro.push(r);
            return map;
        }
        else{
            string r = "MOVEU PARA (";
            this->x = x_l;
            this->y = y_l;
            r = r.append(to_string(x));
            r = r.append(",");
            r = r.append(to_string(y));
            r = r.append(")");
            this->registro.push(r);
            return map;
        }
    }

    if(acao == "COLETAR" || acao == "*COLETAR"){
        int i = this->x;
        int j = this->y;
        if( map[i][j] == 'R'){
            this->recursos++;
            string r = "RECURSOS COLETADOS EM (";
            r = r.append(to_string(i));
            r = r.append(",");
            r = r.append(to_string(j));
            r = r.append(")");
            this->registro.push(r);
            char** aux = map;
            aux[i][j] = '.';
            return aux;
        }
        else{
            string r = "IMPOSSIVEL COLETAR RECURSOS EM (";
            r = r.append(to_string(i));
            r = r.append(",");
            r = r.append(to_string(j));
            r = r.append(")");
            this->registro.push(r);
            return map;
        }
    }

    if(acao == "ELIMINAR" || acao == "*ELIMINAR"){
        int i = this->x;
        int j = this->y;
        if( map[i][j] == 'H'){
            this->aliens++;
            string r = " ALIEN ELIMINADO EM (";
            r = r.append(to_string(i));
            r = r.append(",");
            r = r.append(to_string(j));
            r = r.append(")");
            this->registro.push(r);
            char** aux = map;
            aux[i][j] = '.';
            return aux;
        }
        else{
            string r = "IMPOSSIVEL ELIMINAR ALIEN EM (";
            r = r.append(to_string(i));
            r = r.append(",");
            r = r.append(to_string(j));
            r = r.append(")");
            this->registro.push(r);
            return map;
        }
    }

    if(acao == "ATIVAR" || acao == "*ATIVAR"){
        if(this->ativado == 1){
            string r = "BASE: ROBO ";
            r = r.append(to_string(this->robo_n));
            r = r.append(" JA ESTA EM MISSAO");
            cout << r << endl;
            return map;
        }
        else{
            this->ativado = 1;
            this->x = 0;
            this->y = 0;
            string r = "BASE: ROBO ";
            r = r.append(to_string(this->robo_n));
            r = r.append(" SAIU EM MISSAO");
            cout << r << endl;
            return map;
        }
    }

    if(acao == "RETORNAR" || acao == "*RETORNAR"){
        if(this->ativado == 1){
            this->ativado = 0;
            string r = "BASE: ROBO ";
            r = r.append(to_string(this->robo_n));
            r = r.append(" RETORNOU ALIENS ");
            r = r.append(to_string(this->aliens));
            r = r.append(" RECURSOS ");
            r = r.append(to_string(this->recursos));
            cout << r << endl;
            this->aliens_base += this->aliens;
            this->recursos_base += this->recursos;
            this->aliens = 0;
            this->recursos = 0;
            while(!this->registro.empty()){
                this->registro.pop();
            }
            return map;
        }
        else{
            string r = "BASE: ROBO ";
            r = r.append(to_string(this->robo_n));
            r = r.append(" NAO ESTA EM MISSAO");
            return map;
        }
    }
}


char** Robo::executar(char** map){
    if(this->ativado == 1){
        char** aux = map;
        while(!this->comandos.empty()){
            char** aux_1 = exec_comando(this->comandos.front(), aux);
            this->comandos.pop();
            aux = aux_1;
        }
        return aux;
    }
    else{
        string r = "BASE: ROBO ";
        r = r.append(to_string(this->robo_n));
        r = r.append(" NAO ESTA EM MISSAO");
        cout << r << endl;
        return map;
    }
}


char** Robo::add_comando(string s, char** map){
    if(s.find("ATIVAR")!= string::npos){
        return exec_comando(s, map);
    }

    if(s.find("EXECUTAR")!= string::npos){
        executar(map);
        return map;
    }

    if(s.find("RELATORIO")!= string::npos){
        print_registro();
        return map;
    }

    if(s.find("RETORNAR")!= string::npos){
        return exec_comando(s, map);
    }

    if(s.find("*")!= string::npos){
        return exec_comando(s, map);
    }

    else{
        this->comandos.push(s);
    }
}


void Robo::print_registro(){
    while(!this->registro.empty()){
        string r = "ROBO ";
        r = r.append(to_string(this->robo_n));
        r = r.append(": ");
        cout << r << this->registro.front() << endl;
        registro.pop();
    }
}










#include "Robo.hpp"
#include <queue>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;


char** aloc_map(int map_lines, int map_columns){
    int n;
    char **Char_Map;
    Char_Map = new char *[map_lines];
    for(n = 0 ; n < map_lines ; n++){
        Char_Map[n] = new char[map_columns];
    }
    return Char_Map;
}


void fill_str_map(string* line_str, string aux_str, int map_lines, ifstream& arq_map){
    for(int i = 0 ; i < map_lines ; i++){
        getline(arq_map, aux_str);
        line_str[i] = aux_str;
    }
}


void fill_char_map(char** Char_Map, string* line_str, int map_lines, int map_columns){
    for(int m = 0 ; m < map_lines ; m++){
        strcpy(Char_Map[m], line_str[m].c_str());
    }
}


string get_rnumber(string com_n){
    string s;
    stringstream ss(com_n);
    getline(ss, s, ' ');
    getline(ss, s, ' ');
    return s;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    try{

    //Abertura dos arquivos
    ifstream arq_map;
    arq_map.open(argv[1]);
    if(!arq_map){
        cout << "Erro na abertura do arquivo" << endl;
    }
    ifstream arq_com;
    arq_com.open(argv[2]);
    if(!arq_com){
        cout << "Erro na abertura do arquivo" << endl;
    }

    string size_aux_str;
    getline(arq_map, size_aux_str);
    int map_lines = stoi(size_aux_str);
    int map_columns = stoi(size_aux_str);

    int com_lines = 0;
    string aux2_str;
    while(getline(arq_com, aux2_str)){
        com_lines++;
    }
    arq_com.close();

    arq_com.open(argv[2]);
    string com_str[com_lines];
    string aux3_str;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < com_lines ; i++){
        getline(arq_com, aux3_str);
        com_str[i] = aux3_str;
    }


    string line_str[map_lines];
    string aux_str;

    
    fill_str_map(line_str, aux_str, map_lines, arq_map);

    
    char **Char_Map = aloc_map(map_lines, map_columns);

    
    fill_char_map(Char_Map, line_str, map_lines, map_columns);


    Robo r;


    Robo lista[50];

    for(int i = 0 ; i < 50 ; i++){
        lista[i] = Robo(i);
    }
  
    for(int i=0 ; i < com_lines ; i++){
        string aux_str = com_str[i];
        string rnumber = get_rnumber(aux_str);
        int robo_n = stoi(rnumber);
        Char_Map = lista[robo_n].add_comando(aux_str, Char_Map);
    }

    return 0;
    }catch (exception& e){
        cout << e.what() << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Something in your program caused [`std::terminate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate) to be called (for example an unhandled exception). Unfortunately something else happened during the program cleanup which caused `std::terminate` to be called *again*. Which is bad. What you need to do is to learn how to use a *debugger* to catch bad things happening (like exceptions and crashes in general).

Comment: There is nothing wrong in the source code you have shown.

Comment: You also seem to have fallen into the trap of writing too much code without testing (common for beginners). Write only a *small* piece of code, solving a very limited and single problem, and then build with extra warnings enabled (and treat them as errors. When it builds and *runs* as expected (doing several tests to make sure it works) then you continue with the next little small piece of code.

Comment: Whatever problem you are having it's not caused by the code you have posted, which is fine.

Comment: You should post your main class too (I'm assuming this isn't it).

Comment: It's a common beginner mistake to think that where the code crashes is where the error is. But unfortunately programming is more complicated than that.

Comment: Please, provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I've updated the code!

Comment: There's a lot of code there, please try to reduce it to a [mre], it'll probably help you find the problem too. Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: This needs a serious trim. When writing non-trivial code, do try and have some unit tests, like those you get with [catch2](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2) to validate the parts you're building before you get in way too deep and have heaps of untested code you're trying to debug all at once.

Comment: Some observations: **Stay away from pointers**, especially as a beginner. This goes double for `**` pointers, and triple for `***`. Use Standard Library containers like `std::vector` and wrappers like `std::string`. Even for veteran programmers pointers can be an absolute nightmare, as with every pointer comes *responsibility* you often don't want or need. Try and use references, especially `const` references, as a way of passing around data. It's significantly more efficient and *considerably* safer. You can easily pass in a bad pointer, but a bad reference is very awkward to create.

Comment: I see many places where you copy and return pointers where you might think that you're creating new structures (there is only one of your `char**` "maps" in the entire program.) There is also a missing return in `Robo::add_comando`.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but those two constructors can be written as just one if you declare it as `Robo(int n = 0)`. Also, get rid of this `this->`s; they're entirely redundant and distracting. And read about initializer lists: `Robo::Robo() : robo_n(0), aliens(0), recursos(0), aliens_base(0), recursos_base(0), ativado(0) {}`. That doesn't make much difference here, but when a class has members that have their own constructors it becomes much more important.